# Documentation on how to deploy the extension library to notes clients?

Tags: installation, xpages, xpages-extlib, xpinc

Is there a single document that explains how to deploy the Openntf extension library to notes clients so they can run an XPages application in a native Notes session. 
I have a client that does not have a lot of Admin experience (nor do I) that needs to do this. This is into a N/D 9.0.1 environment and I have found bits and pieces for 8.5.3 but no single document that says do 1. 2. 3. etc.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8GZM9A ?

Comment: Knut - yes -- is there differences with 9.0.1 or something that is a bit more of a tutorial?

Comment: How to deploy the extension libray is described in chapter 2 of the XPages Extension Library book.

Comment: Fredrik  -- Thanks I remember reading that when I first got the book but skimmed over the client side. That will do fine. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is in the XPages Extension Library Book, which is great (I had forgotten to look there. However, because it is such a core issue I would have hoped to find it in the IBM on-line documentation. While I think that the XPages Extension Library book is an essential part of an XPages Developers Library I find IBM's documentation to be lacking. Searching the web (and I do that a lot) we can find bits and pieces but many core issues are really hard to find.